# How to install Outlook Web Add-In to a Distribution Group in Exchange Server 2013?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am trying to install a Outlook web add-in for a Distribution Group on Exchange Server 2013. I have created a group of users and in accordance with [Install or remove add-ins for Outlook for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/install-or-remove-outlook-add-ins), I am trying to assign the app to only that group.

When I try to run the command from the Exchange PowerShell, it is unable to find the AppId of my Outlook Web Add-in.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$a = Get-DistributionGroupMember MyGroup-Users
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Set-App -Identity badb297b-b8e8-41e1-9513-ff821c15189c -OrganizationApp -ProvidedTo SpecificUsers -UserList $a.Identity -DefaultStateForUser Enabled
The operation couldn't be performed because 'badb297b-b8e8-41e1-9513-ff821c15189c' couldn't be found.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-App], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=WIN-MASKED,RequestId=207e8697-a42c-4460-af5e-fccfe027c8db,TimeStamp=7/6/201
   8 10:59:33 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 291FF391,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.E
  xtension.SetApp
    + PSComputerName        : win-j0qd2spo6mv.mydomain.com
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried installing the app for all users in organisation before and after running these commands.

The guid is the one from the Id section in the XML manifest of Outlook Web Add-in. Am I supposed to use the same Id as AppId or it is something else?

Comment: Run `Get-App -OrganizationApp |FL DisplayName,AppID`, look for your add-in and compare the AppID.